# 「*.dll」や「lib*.so」は共有ライブラリとのことですが、それぞれ仕様はありますか？

Tags: dll

「*.dll」や「lib*.so」は共有ライブラリとのことですが、それぞれ仕様はありますか？
例えば「*.dll」として仕様があり「HTML5仕様」のように「*.dll仕様」としてどこかで公開されていますか？
それとも「*.dll」は単にこの拡張子を共有ライブラリとしてみなすという意味でしかなく、それぞれの仕様は、同じ「*.dll」でもそれぞれのプロジェクトごとに異なるのですか？

Comment: 最後の「また～」以降の部分を削除しました。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.dllはWindowsで使われる共有ライブラリの拡張子です。Portable Executableフォーマットで定義されているようです。
[Wikipedia: Portable Executable](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable)
[PE(Portable Executable)ファイルフォーマットの概要](http://shopping2.gmobb.jp/htdmnr/www08/mcc/doc/pe.html)
[Microsoft: PE 形式](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/win32/debug/pe-format)

lib.soはLinuxで使われる共有オブジェクトの拡張子です。Executable and Linkable Format (ELF)フォーマットが使用されているようです。
[実行ファイル形式のELFって何？](https://www.itmedia.co.jp/help/tips/linux/l0448.html)
[Wikipedia: Executable and Linkable Format](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format)